# Are there any differences in merging two repos than merging master+branch of one repo?

Tags: git, version-control, merge

I just tested merging between two repositories locally, whereas the second one I cloned from the original repository.

I made a change in the clone and was able to merge it back easily. Now my question would be, on a general level, is there something that does not work at all or not that well when following a workflow that is based on merging repositories rather than branches?